Kiwi tcms not sending email notification after upgrade
I have upgraded kiwi tcms to latest version 13.5
Once upgrade done I could't send any email for any processing.
Sample scenarios

While resetting password. no email received. it returns 500.
While editing and saving test case or plan no email received. it returns 500.


All email notification was working fine before upgrade. After upgrade to latest version we are facing this. How to resolve this email sending issue in v13.5
I tried to run below sendtestemail command which returns OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestemail test@test.com

Thanks in advance.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
